# Sending a chat message to a LAN game with Python

Tags: python, sockets

This might be a confusing question...
But take for example the game Battlefield2.
Is it in any way possible to send chat messages to the game through Python? The reason I am asking this is because I've seen messages appear from no where on various games, and want to know if it's possible. Now, the way I understand a packet is like this...

It's a small collection of data with a sender IP address and a recipient IP address. Contained within the packet is the data. So, in theory... If the 'packet name' for the chat message is like:

```
SRV_CHAT|<Sender_Info>|<Message Text>
(For example): SRV_CHAT|10.1.1.5,Player1|hello, how's the game?
```

Does that mean that I can create a Python script to send my own message to a LAN game and have it appear? If it is possible, how can I go about dissecting the actual packet information in order to discover any parameters? What I mean by this, is finding that data contained in there...

It's just a thought and a question I've had for a long time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is *technically* possible. But not very feasible.

What you said about packets is essentially correct, and you can read more about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet).

However, beyond packets, there are entire networks of protocols that determine where they go, and who receives them, you can read about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_IP).

This means that if you were to manage to emulate the connection to the games server, you could possibly send data to that server, but most likely the server does not support random connections simply sending messages, and the server expects to receive connections which are made by other game clients, and unless you can emulate the clients responses and requests correctly, it will probably not work.

This means that your idea to use Python to directly connect to a server and send messages in the format similar to what you suggested would not work.

---

However. The server most definitely supports server messages, messages that are sent FROM the server itself into the game, usually if someone hosts a game for instance, they can send messages as the game server (host) of the game. Or, if it is a dedicated server, they might not be in the game itself and send messages to the players in the game through a management console.

It is most likely that many 'plugins' or methods to hook into this control are available, meaning that you could send a message to the application running the game server, telling it that it should send a message into the game.

This would be less emulation and more implementation of the games management system.

It is important to note, that many games are different, and their operation is different, meaning this may or may not work, depending on what options are available. It is my experience that games like Battlefield2 (which I have not played) usually have these tools builtin.

---

Specifically with BattleField2, there are some links I found that you might like.

http://www.gamefront.com/files/listing/pub2/Battlefield_2/Official_Server_Files/Dedicated_Server/
http://www.bf2cc.com/

Comment: This is quite an incredible answer. Thank you so much for this. Best answer as soon as it's avaliable.
Thanks again!